# May I change my high-voted incorrect not-accepted answer to say the opposite?

Tags: discussion, answers, edits, fastest-gun, ethics

Let's say I answered a question and got a load of upvotes (at least 20) in the first 15 minutes of the question's existence.

Right from the beginning, there was a comment that my answer was far-out in left-field, and a few minutes later at least one, fully documented answer conclusively demonstrates that my answer is completely wrong.

Is it ethical to completely change my answer to say what's actually right, or must / should I delete it?

I tend to deleting it, especially as the votes were for the previous answer, though I've also seen the opposite demonstrated.

Just to clarify: The question was interpreted identically (and correctly) by everyone.

Comment: It depends, of course, but you _should_ delete it if there already is a good answer. IMO it's useless to either state the exact same thing as the other answer again, or have a huge block of strike-through text prefixed with "the following is completely wrong, look at the other answer instead". I'd only keep it if the answer has further information which would be important to other people finding the question (and then of course edit it to focus on that information).

Comment: The only time I've been in a situation similar to this one, there was another, correct and complete, answer which I upvoted and deleted my own answer.

Comment: Another vote for deletion.

Comment: Leave it there, mention that it's wrong in the first paragraph, and explain why you and others believed it to be correct at the time.

Comment: Gosh, 20 up-votes in the first 15 minutes! Why this never happens to me??? Uhm - it's not just that - I haven't even *witnessed* anything like this.

Comment: @zespri: Just get hit by the super-collider, and if yours is the most-upvoted answer, it will more than likely get *more* than 20 upvotes in that time.

Comment: @Deduplicator Don't delete the answer if its useful to others. I have upvoted answers which solved my problems, without testing if it solverd the OP's problem.

Comment: "conclusively demonstrates" as in "anyone can see it is wrong by reading correct answer" or "I happen to spend 10 years in the field and clearly *Foo* mentioned in answer implies X, which in turn implies Y and *obviously to anyone* approach suggested does not work because of Y" (while in reality there about 5 people on the planet how can see this chain of conclusions).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Anyone with a functional level of (technical) english can verify the reasoning of the correct answers. Extracting the information from the docs is something else naturally.

Comment: @Deduplicator - I'd consider to delete my answer is such case - it does not seem like you'd save anyone by adding "don't go this way" comments to your answer - basically effort to improve answer will not make site better.

Answer (score 114):

Stop and think!

If you got a lot of up-votes, that means you were not the only one misinterpreting the question. That could be due to the *question* (i.e., a candidate for "Unclear what you are asking", even though the other answerer figured it out) ... but it could also be that the topic is not as clear-cut as one may think.

That means even if you delete your answer, someone else may submit a similar -- also *wrong*! -- answer.

In this case, I'd swallow my pride and edit the answer to add *it is wrong*, and save face by a honest attempt of explaining *why I thought it was the right answer*. That, in itself, could help others.

Comment: "If you got a lot of up-votes, that means you were not the only one misinterpreting the question" - I've seen way too many random drive-by upvotes to even consider this interpretation. People upvote out of tons of reasons; it does not neccessarily correlate with usefulness of the post, especially when the upvotes occur shortly after the answer was posted (meaning the people upvoting are random SO users finding the question in their feed, not googlers who have the same problem as OP).

Comment: I think the most common reason for quick up votes is when an answer is from a high rep user and seems simple and elegant and already has up votes  - people will often vote it up without even testing its validity because it "seems like it should be right"

Comment: @MattCoubrough: To be honest, I personally usually upvote on a gut feeling, I don't take the time to actually reproduce the issue and check that the answer really solves it. And I somehow suspect that I am not the only one...

Comment: @MatthieuM.: that's why I believe it's important to point out the relevance of "gut feelings", *especially* when they turn out to be wrong! Remember [the Monty Hall Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem), where reportedly thousands of budding mathematicians including "nearly 1,000 with PhDs" got it wrong.

Comment: @Jongware: Yes, I totally agree.

Comment: Stipulating that a great many upvotes may be drive-bys, does that really invalidate the argument in this answer? At least one person was confused enough to post the wrong answer – annotating it as wrong still seems the best approach. _Especially_ if people are upvoting you because you are a high rep user.

Comment: Stack Overflow is full of people who upvote without understanding the answer that they're upvoting.  I don't think we can solve this easily.

Comment: *"...that means you were not the only one misinterpreting the question."* So delete the answer **and** edit the question to clarify. Leaving an incorrect answer is not the solution.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Just to clarify, the question was not in any way mis-interpreted, the answer was just completely wrong.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Thanks for clarifying. Yeah, definitely delete. Nice to see people like yourself who understand the value of quality answers and prefer it to rep points. :-)

Answer (score 12):

My reaction would be to leave it, but edit it to make clear you think it's wrong and why it's wrong.

Clearly enough people agreed with you to upvote, despite your being wrong, so other people would make the same mistake. A wrong answer that clearly explains why it's wrong contributes to the net wisdom of the world, and so is worth having.

I wouldn't change it completely - especially not if another answer has been posted that's actually right. If you feel you can still add more, putting in *another* separate answer and then referencing that might be appropriate.

Answer (score 11):

I would delete the answer. An incorrect answer should always be deleted.

If there's reason to believe that people will misinterpret the question in the way that you did, edit the question to fix that.

Comment: I think additionally to "misinterpret question" (which seem not to be the case here) one should consider if other people will try solve it the same wrong way, but the fact it is wrong way is not clear for regular person based on correct answer. There could be some information/steps known to person proficient in the particular field (and thus skipped from correct answer) that "conclusively demonstrates that my answer is completely wrong" but unknown to outside/first time person.