# Dealing with an answer upvoted despite being wrong and later updated to reflect the facts

Tags: discussion, answers, wrong-answers

A short while ago I encountered an answer that was completely wrong, so I downvoted it and left a comment explaining why it is bad (based on my knowledge of normative sources and some general grasp of the language). Someone else also posted their comment (though I don't know if they downvoted as well).

However, the answer had somehow managed to attract a few upvotes despite being wrong, and I am puzzled as to why this happened. A couple of minutes later the author decided to update his answer to reflect the facts that he learned from the comments. The answer in its current form doesn't appeal to me either, as it doesn't explain things well and even contains a statement that might be quite confusing to individuals who don't happen to have enough knowledge on the subject. Now the answer has four upvotes which, as far as I'm concerned, had been cast before its transformation to the final form. As of this writing, my downvote still holds.

What should I do about this answer, given that it was changed in its entirety? Is it left to the upvoters to decide whether they wish to keep their votes (though we probably can't rely on that, as they *did* upvote a wrong answer in the first place)?

Should such an answer even exist? There already is a much better (and, fortunately, accepted by the OP) answer on the question.

Comment: Hold the downvote and clarify this and why commenting at the answer. Some users will refrain to delete or better improve their answers, as long they've got some rep with that already.

Comment: [Sometimes all you can is... let it go.](https://xkcd.com/386/)

Comment: Related: [May I change my high-voted incorrect not-accepted answer to say the opposite?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284161/may-i-change-my-high-voted-incorrect-not-accepted-answer-to-say-the-opposite)

Comment: Related again: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/notification-on-edit-of-downvoted-content

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255198/how-to-handle-historical-highly-upvoted-but-completely-incorrect-answers?rq=1

Comment: There are idiots in every community.  You can pretty much guarantee that the more clearly you explain why an answer is wrong, the more likely somebody is to come along and upvote the answer afterwards, despite your explanation.  Or maybe _because_ of your explanation, because they feel sorry for the respondent.  Just pat yourself on the back for being smarter than them, and move on.

Comment: @DavidWallace: Let's not also forget the idiocy that is sometimes found in the reflection. People who get wrapped up in down voting and being "right" about their positions are one of the biggest problems on SO today. Hopefully the comment about "pat yourself on the back for being smarter than them, and move on" was reverse psychology to help this person stop being part of the problem, but it's certainly dangerous for people who down vote to think they are smarter than others or that their opinion matters more than 1/n where n is the number of registered users on the system.

Comment: @GeorgScholz, this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/29867592/960757 I guess.

Comment: @GeorgScholz I meant the answer linked by TLama.

Comment: @rhino, I can delete that comment if you want to keep that in secret (though it's easy to find it through your activity page).

Comment: @TLama There is no use in deleting it, as indeed the answer can be easily found there (and, in fact, I expected someone to find it sooner or later).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What should I do about this answer, given that it was changed in its entirety?

Nothing. If your vote is still valid, leave it in place. At most leave a comment with regard to the revised content. But apart from that you'll just have to move on.

If the answer really is bad, all you can hope for is that future voters will tip the scale in the appropriate direction.

> Is it left to the upvoters to decide whether they wish to keep their votes

Yes. That is entirely up to them. Nobody else can nor will interfere with that. If they don't come back to the answer to revise their votes, they are there to stay.