# Completely replacing own upvoted answer with entirely different answer instead of submitting new answer

Tags: discussion, edits, upvotes

The discussion and answers on [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284161/may-i-change-my-high-voted-incorrect-not-accepted-answer-to-say-the-opposite) unanimously advise the asker not to edit his/her own highly-upvoted answer into a different answer that contradicts the original answer, but rather to delete it or to add a note to it.

Is that just advice, or is it law? Is it reportable behavior? Should it be reportable behavior? Is there any remedy?

---

In my view an upvote is something given to a particular answer. Without the upvoter's consent, the author of that answer may not transfer it to an entirely different answer that has essentially nothing in common with what the upvoter upvoted.

Of course, the fuzzy meaning of "essentially" could introduce edge-cases. I'm not asking where the edge is; I'm asking whether there is (or should be) an interior case at all.

Comment: I am sure you are intentionally trying to ask this in a generic way, but there are all sorts of edge cases. Some more context would probably be useful.  I am assuming there is a specific answer that someone else asked that was edited, or an answer of yours you want to edit.  Could you share it?

Comment: However, a downvote just because someone changed the answer, is **never** appropriate.  The tool tip on the downvote button on answers says "This answer is not useful".  If you vote only because of the user or the previous state of the question or circumstances around the answer itself that is not about the content and accuracy of the answer, then you are doing a disservice to everyone as the vote doesn't reflect the quality of the answer anymore.  (If the answer is still wrong after editing or the answer is rolled back to the incorrect version, then downvote away)

Comment: There is no need for a "remedy". The crux of the matter is that a wrong answer has become a right answer. From our "best repository of knowledge" standpoint, that's a good thing, and the only thing that ultimately matters. That User B may feel "cheated" because User A's answer started on the wrong foot but not theirs is irrelevant. In this situation, I would recommend moving on.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Transferring upvotes to an entirely different answer without the consent of the upvoters subverts SO's mechanism for establishing usefulness. SO does not pass judgement on the correctness of answers. It uses the upvote system. For all SO knows, those upvotes are being transferred to an incorrect answer, without upvoters' consent. Should that be allowed?

Comment: @tennenrishin you changed your hypothetical example.  Your original premise was changing a wrong answer to a right one.  Now your example is changing a right answer to a wrong answer.

Comment: @psubsee2003 So it's okay to transfer votes without the voters' consent as long as you are transferring them to what you consider to be the "right" answer? If answer-authors can arbitrate between "right" and "wrong" answers, why do we even have the voting system?

Comment: There is no rule that says you can't, but the people who are against said action are free to roll it back, and if an edit war ensues, bring it to meta discussion to get a consensus based decision on it.

Comment: That's the thing with stackoverflow... there are very few hard set in stone rules, most of the "rules" we have are community-derived and community enforced (usually in the form of voting and editing on a case-by-case basis) Trying to generalize this seems pretty useless to me.

Comment: @KevinB I'm all for minimal regulation but I think the voting system is a somewhat sacred mechanism in SO. (It facilitates all the self-regulation in the first place.) Since it is very easy to post a new answer as a new answer, it is hard to see why anyone would *ever* want to replace an entire answer unless they want to transfer upvotes to what was not upvoted.

Comment: There is no transference of votes though. The votes are all still on the same answer. Sure, the content or meaning of the answer may have changed, but it's still the same answer. After it has been edited, the votes can be changed. I understand that it's unlikely for people to come back and re-vote, which is why the general consensus in that situation is to create a new answer instead, or to simply delete the answer. All i'm saying is it isn't against "the rules". Sure, it is likely frowned upon by the community.

Comment: @KevinB It is the answer's content that was upvoted, not the container. So I understand now that there are no rules against it. The other part of my question was: *Shouldn't* it be against the rules? What legitimate reason could anyone ever have to replace an answer rather than submitting a new answer as a new answer?

Comment: @tennenrishin, as an example, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4015874/464709) is an old answer of mine. Timeline: my answer was initially wrong, it was proven wrong by another answerer but I could not delete it because it had been accepted in-between. My only recourse was to substantially edit the answer to put it in line with the other one. End result: two right answers under the question, but I got to keep the votes.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi You did *not* replace the old answer, you unendorsed and added to it. That is exactly what I am advocating. My question is about completely replacing upvoted content with entirely new content.

Comment: @tennenrishin, ah, I get your point now. So you're asking about what should happen had I, say, reworded the right answer into mine? That's not easy to answer indeed, I would guess it depends on the level of plagiarism involved and whether or not this is repeated behavior. In the general case, I don't think it would be okay, but the end result would still benefit the community, so...